# using if else in sql server ( un pivot)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to run only one sql statement based on the product id:

If product id = 0 then I want to run this sql statement:

```
SELECT QuarterName as Quarters, QuarterValue
  FROM
    (
       SELECT month_key,
         sum(Q1)Q1, sum(Q2)Q2, sum(Q3)Q3, sum(Q4)Q4
          FROM myTable
          where line_item_id = '2548' 
            group by month_key 
            ) stu
                 UNPIVOT
                    (QuarterValue FOR QuarterName IN (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
                     ) AS QTR 
                        where month_key =2016
```

If product id <> 0 then I want to run this sql statement:

```
SELECT QuarterName as Quarters, QuarterValue
  FROM
    (
       SELECT month_key,
         sum(Q1)Q1, sum(Q2)Q2, sum(Q3)Q3, sum(Q4)Q4
          FROM myTable
          where line_item_id = '2548' 
          and product_id = 'wq2745'
            group by month_key 
            ) stu
                 UNPIVOT
                    (QuarterValue FOR QuarterName IN (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
                     ) AS QTR 
                        where month_key =2016
```

The difference is the first query does not use the product id in the where clause but the 2nd one does.  I am running these sql queries in C# application so the product id value is coming as a parameters based on some drop down boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `isnull(nullif())`:

```
declare @ProductId varchar(6);
  set @ProductId = 'wq2745' 

begin;
  select 
      Quarters = QuarterName
    , QuarterValue
  from (
   select month_key
    , sum(Q1) Q1
    , sum(Q2) Q2
    , sum(Q3) Q3
    , sum(Q4) Q4
   from myTable
   where line_item_id = '2548' 
    and product_id = isnull(nullif(@ProductId,'0'),product_id)
   group by month_key
   ) stu
  unpivot(QuarterValue for QuarterName in (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)) as QTR
  where month_key = 2016
end;
```

---

or using `If` and two statements this way:

```
declare @ProductId varchar(6);
  set @ProductId = 'wq2745' 

if @ProductId = '0'
begin;
  select 
      Quarters = QuarterName
    , QuarterValue
  from (
   select month_key
    , sum(Q1) Q1
    , sum(Q2) Q2
    , sum(Q3) Q3
    , sum(Q4) Q4
   from myTable
   where line_item_id = '2548'
   group by month_key
   ) stu
  unpivot(QuarterValue for QuarterName in (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)) as QTR
  where month_key = 2016
end;

if @ProductId != '0'
begin;
  select QuarterName as Quarters
   , QuarterValue
  from (
   select month_key
    , sum(Q1) Q1
    , sum(Q2) Q2
    , sum(Q3) Q3
    , sum(Q4) Q4
   from myTable
   where line_item_id = '2548' 
    and product_id = @ProductId
   group by month_key
   ) stu
  unpivot(QuarterValue for QuarterName in (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)) as QTR
  where month_key = 2016
end;
```

Comment: thanks, i am going to try this but before i do that i want to tell you that the product id is not always fixed, it changes as the drop down is changed so do we need to initialize the value of the product id like the way you did here?

Comment: @moe No you do not, but you do need to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two distinct queries here. You can easily handle this with a case expression. Something like this.

```
SELECT QuarterName as Quarters, QuarterValue
  FROM
    (
       SELECT month_key,
         sum(Q1)Q1, sum(Q2)Q2, sum(Q3)Q3, sum(Q4)Q4
          FROM myTable
          where line_item_id = '2548' 
          and product_id = case @ProductId when <> 0 then 'wq2745' else product_id end
            group by month_key 
            ) stu
                 UNPIVOT
                    (QuarterValue FOR QuarterName IN (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
                     ) AS QTR 
                        where month_key =2016
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `case` expression be the other way around? `case @ProductId when '0' then product_id else @ProductId end`

Comment: @SqlZim yes I think so. Oops.